# Not Able To use for-loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, code-conversion

** I want to use two *for-loops* instead of two *while-loops* **

```
i = 7
while i >= 1:
    j = i
    while j <= 7:
        print(j, end ="  ")
        J += 1
    i -= 1
    print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the `for-loop` equivalent:

```
for i in range(7, 0, -1):
    j = i
    for j in range(i, 8):
        print(j, end="  ")
    print()
```

The key is the correct use of [`range(start, stop, step)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). See also [this](https://pynative.com/python-range-function/).